# Will memory leak if do multiple glBindBuffers on same buffer object, before call glDeleteBuffers?

Tags: opengl

**UPDATE** I just discovered my question is likely a duplicate of [If you call glBufferData after already calling it on a buffer, is there a memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983416/if-you-call-glbufferdata-after-already-calling-it-on-a-buffer-is-there-a-memory?rq=1)

Hopefully my question is still useful to someone, as I give code samples, rather than merely mentioning the gl function calls, as in that Q&A.

---

I don't understand the relationship between `glGenBuffers / glBindBuffer / glBufferData` and `gldeletebuffers`.

Consider drawing a sequence of lines (a line strip). The original sequence is drawn over some number of frames, but then new user input increases the number of lines.

My first thought is to re-use the buffer object name assigned by `glGenBuffers`, when the size changes. But since the buffer size needs to be larger, I can't use the existing buffer as-is.

NOTE: At this time, I would rather not assume some "maximum size", allocate that, and then do sub-data calls for the size I currently need.

Consider code based on this example:
[When should I call glDeleteBuffers()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937285/when-should-i-call-gldeletebuffers)

If I had done these lines in an initialization function before drawing the first frame (code may not compile -- I'm concerned about the call sequence, not the exact parameters to pass -- I'm actually working in C# under Xamarin using OpenTK to access OPENGL ES 2.0, but it is easier to find examples in C++ using opengl):

```
GLuint VBO;

void init(int size, float* data) {
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

which many frames later (or when app exits) is released via:

```
void destroy() {
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
}
```

But now I want to have a "re_init" function that allocates a different size, what exactly do I need to do?

I could re-assign a new VBO buffer name:

```
void re_init(newSize, newData) {
    destroy();
    init(newSize, newData);
}
```

But this seems like overkill. What is the *minimum* work that I can do?  And is that any more efficient than the brute-force destroy/create-a-new-one above?

It seems that any set of calls I do works, but i don't know whether the result is leaking memory or not. I will eventually need to learn how to test for memory leaks in the environment I am in, but right now I want to get the theory right, in hopes that I will write code that is both efficient and non-leaking.

Will this leak memory?

```
void re_init(newSize, newData) {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, newSize, newData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

That is, I haven't done `glDeleteBuffers` on the old buffer, because doing so freed the VBO buffer name, and I am trying to find out how to not do so.

One question is whether there is a way to re-use a VBO buffer name, with data of a different size?

Or am I better off sticking to the simple model of freeing the buffer ***and its name*** every time I need to change buffer size? (That is what glDeleteBuffers seems to do.)

Comment: `glGenBuffers` allocates the buffers. `glBindBuffer(GL_SOMEBUFFER_TYPE, id)` effectively sets a global variable `somebuffer_type` to the passed buffer, and most buffer functions like `glBufferData` use this global variable as the buffer it's operating on.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: Thx - that makes the role of `glBindBuffer` clearer. But what you say about `glGenBuffers` raises a question:  glGenBuffers is not told the ***size*** to allocate, so it can't actually allocate memory; my understanding is that it reserves a buffer id. For there to be a memory leak, some actual data area would need to be lost track of. Since there isn't a data size until `glBufferData`, I presume that is when there is an actual "allocation"?

Comment: `glBufferData` resizes/reallocates the buffer as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glBufferData` will replace the content of the buffer object - as indicated is the [spec/doc](http://docs.gl/gl4/glBufferData), "*while creating the new storage, any pre-existing data store is deleted*" - so this won't leak memory.

For efficiency, there are many factors to consider, and no universal guidelines - I suggest you profile in your application, once you have a real use case with your data.

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 separate entities in play here:

- A buffer **name**. Since it is an integer value lot of people like to call this an "id". But if you read official OpenGL documentation, it is always called "name".
- A buffer **object**. This is the object that contains the state attributes, like the current size, the usage flags, etc.
- A buffer **store**. This is the memory that contains the actual buffer content.

With these definitions, we can describe what each call is doing:

- `glGenBuffers()` creates buffer names.
- `glBindBuffer()` creates a buffer object the first time the given name is bound, and makes it the current buffer for other calls operating on buffers.
- `glBufferData()` deletes the current buffer store if there already was one, and creates a new buffer store.
- `glBufferSubData()` modifies data in the existing data store.
- `glDeleteBuffers()` deletes the buffer names, as well as the associated buffer objects and buffer stores if they exist.

This means that calling `glBufferData()` on the same buffer object multiple times is perfectly fine, and will not cause any memory leaks.

A subtle detail in the list above is that `glGenBuffers()` does not create buffer objects. That only happens the first time the name is bound. This does not really matter for buffer objects, but it is important to understand for other types of objects (like textures) that have the same behavior.